# Locate a number in an array with a special ordering

Tags: matlab

Below are two examples of arrays (with a special ordering with odd numbers on one side, and even number on the other side) I have, with some given `len`:

```
9  7  5  3  1  2  4  6  8

11  9  7  5  3  1  2  4  6  8  10
```

For some value `z`, I want to find the column the value is in. MATLAB code I wrote:

```
if z == 1
   column = ceil(len/2);   
elseif logical(mod(z,2))
   column = ceil(len/2) - (z-1)/2;
else
   column = ceil(len/2) + z/2;
end
```

Does this above locate the correct column?

Comment: What's the context — why do you want to do this? Is `len` always odd? If not, can you provide an example of what an even-length array would look like?

Comment: @200_success♦ yes it is always odd.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the better solution is to compute the column index directly, without the if-else conditions. You can do this by using integer division, and modulo. Consider the following computation breakdown:

```
% declare an int32 value 2
itwo = int32(2)
% compute the position of the column with the value 1
onecol = idivide(len + 1, itwo)
% compute how far away the desired value is from the 1 column
distance = idivide(z, itwo)
% compute the direction of the desired value from the 1 column (-1 is left (odd numbers), +1 is right (even numbers))
direction = 1 - 2 * mod(z, itwo)
```

You can string this together as a 1-liner:

```
column = idivide(len + 1, itwo) + idivide(z, itwo) * (1 - 2 * mod(z, itwo))
```

You can also put it in a function should you choose. I have put together this example here:

https://goo.gl/Oenp85 (and updated for int32 conversion here: https://goo.gl/NgJJhN

Note that it has been a long time since I played with MATLAB.

```
indexOfVal = @(mat, val) idivide(numel(mat) + 1, int32(2)) + idivide(val, int32(2)) * (1 - 2 * mod(val, int32(2)));

x = [9 7 5 3 1 2 4 6 8];

result1 = indexOfVal(x, 9)
result2 = indexOfVal(x, 7)
result3 = indexOfVal(x, 5)
result4 = indexOfVal(x, 3)
result5 = indexOfVal(x, 1)
result6 = indexOfVal(x, 2)
result7 = indexOfVal(x, 4)
result8 = indexOfVal(x, 6)
result9 = indexOfVal(x, 8)
```

Produces:

```
result1 =  1                                                                                                                                                                                                                
result2 =  2                                                                                                                                                                                                                
result3 =  3                                                                                                                                                                                                                
result4 =  4                                                                                                                                                                                                                
result5 =  5                                                                                                                                                                                                                
result6 =  6                                                                                                                                                                                                                
result7 =  7                                                                                                                                                                                                                
result8 =  8                                                                                                                                                                                                                
result9 =  9
```

Comment: @StewieGriffin I have applied the changes I think you want, and added a second running example in a link. Hopefully that encompasses the changes you suggest. Feel free to edit in any other incompatibility fixes with matlab.

Comment: Looks good.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the `if z == 1` special case can be eliminated.  When `z` is 1, then the `logical(mod(z,2))` case applies, and the `- (z-1)/2` term is 0.

Comment: oh thats true. But will it cause error if i include it?

Comment: if i remove it, i have to remove it from a lot of files i created.

Comment: so just want to make sure. `if logical(mod(z,2))
   column = ceil(len/2) - (z-1)/2;
else
   column = ceil(len/2) + z/2;
end` works correctly?